# Flutter/Supabase - getting error with 'or' filter

Tags: postgresql, flutter, supabase-database

I'm trying to build a Supabase query from my Flutter app that uses and 'OR' where clause like

```
goalType = 'steppingStone' OR (goalOpen = true AND goalType != steppingStone)
```

This translates into the rest syntax of...

```
goalType.eq.steppingStone,all(goalOpen.eq.true,goalType.neq.steppingStone)
```

However, when I call this I'm getting a Supabase/Postgress error of

```
PostgrestException(message: "failed to parse logic tree ((goalType.eq.steppingStone,all(goalOpen.eq.true,goalType.neq.steppingStone)))" (line 1, column 33), code: PGRST100, details: unexpected "(" expecting letter, digit, "-", "->>", "->" or delimiter (.), hint: null)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Typo at my end.

The rest param should be

goalType.eq.steppingStone,**add**(goalOpen.eq.true,goalType.neq.steppingStone)

... not ...

goalType.eq.steppingStone,all(goalOpen.eq.true,goalType.neq.steppingStone)